# superscript altering the line height

Tags: html, css

I have a superscript that is messing up the line spacing. How do i make it even?

I tried

```
sup{vertical-align:0; position: relative;}
```

but that doesn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: a superscript that isn't higher than the rest of the text is not a superscript...

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve it by ignoring the `<sup></sup>` tags and directly using something like

```
<span style="position:relative; top:0.3em;">
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to try altering the line height of the sup element to be smaller than the parent text.

```
sup{vertical-align:super; line-height:0.5em;}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscript has lots of examples that you can inspect. Some of them increase the line height of the parent, some do not.

If that isn't working for you, you can also try

```
sup{vertical-align:top;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sup{vertical-align:top; line-height:0.5em;}
```

This works for me, even though I have sup defined in my stylesheet. I have a link, which also has styling applied, between the `<sup>` and `</sup>` tags, but this seems to force the intended effect of keeping the line spacing consistent.